# jQuery code will not run unless stepped through with Firebug

Tags: jquery, firebug

I have a problem with some jQuery code. For some reason it will not run automatically when its supposed to however when stepping through with Firebug it works fine?

I put a breakpoint on the code that's not firing automatically and then press play on Firebug and it works fine if I take away this breakpoint or close down Firebug it does not run? Can somebody please help, I've searched the internet but not found anything relevant.

The code should run when I click a link which will create a jQuery tab on my main page and open an external page onto this tab - The external page also includes jQuery to run a lightbox so had to put an id on the link that I click to activate the lightbox code (this is the code that wont fire without the breakpoint).

Link:

```
 <a onclick="createNewTab('dhtmlgoodies_tabView1','Remote Access','','RemoteAccess.html',true);return false" id="lightbox_load">Remote Access</a>
```

Code not running:

```
$(function(){                   
    // Lighbox Link
    $('#lightbox_load').click(function(){
    $('#RemoteAccessGallery a').lightBox({fixedNavigation:true});        }); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a race condition with your onclick and the jquery .live addition.
What happens if you bring the createNewTab('dhtmlgoodies_tabView1','Remote Access','',... inside click anonymous  function?

Comment: Didnt try it with the lightbox function but tried it with another page that loads a datatable rather than the lightbox and the datatable loads as expected on the new tab but then the tab just disappears?? Just tried the lightbox with the following: `$(function(){
       
    // Lighbox Link
    $('#lightbox_load').click(function(){createNewTab('dhtmlgoodies_tabView1','Remote Access','','RemoteAccess.html',true);return false,
     $('#RemoteAccessGallery a').lightBox({fixedNavigation:true});        }); });
        ` the exact same thing as earlier-works with a breakpoint. not without

Comment: Strange behaviour, normally if something working in the debugger but not normal its a timing issue. Possible to see the complete code somewhere live?

Comment: you were right, both code were running at the same time however the lightbox finished running before the external page is pulled in - I found this out by putting a setTimeout on the lightbox code so i knew it was running after the external page. Just a little work around that will do for my college assignment. Thanks for helping. If you hadnt said about the race condition i never would have realised what was happening!! Thank you

Comment: @Brock thank you I did not want to promote my own questions this way.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
$(function(){                   
    // Lighbox Link
    $('#lightbox_load').live("click", function(){
        $('#RemoteAccessGallery a').lightBox({fixedNavigation:true});
    });
});
```

Comment: Exactly the same things happening, when putting a breakpoint on the first line it runs. Without firebug or without the breakpoint on it doesn't load =(